# Feed the Matrix output to row output in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, metadata

I have df1 which looks like this, which is per unit price of Goods at particular Date:

```
Type         1/1/2019           2/1/2019         3/1/2019
Ac              20                25               30
Fan             10                20               15
Chair           5                 10               10
```

And another data df2 which contains the no of unit sold:

```
Date        Type       Ac        Fan      Chair
1/1/2019    AC, FAN    6         5         0
2/1/2019    Ac         4         0         0
3/1/2019    Chair,Fan  0         4         8
```

So i want my output to include the per unit price as well in the columns, so my outptu will look like this:

```
Date        Type       Ac    Ac.Price     Fan    Fan.Price  Chair     chair.price
1/1/2019    AC, FAN    6       20          5        10         0         5
2/1/2019    Ac         4       25          0        20         0         10
3/1/2019    Chair,Fan  0       30          4        15         8         10
```

I tried `pd.concat([df1,df2]), axis=1)`
but its not workin, can anyone please help me on this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df1 = df1.T.reset_index()

new_df1.columns = list(new_df1.loc[0])
new_df1 = new_df1.drop(index=[0]).rename({'Type':'Date'}, axis=1)

##new_df1

       Date  Ac Fan Chair
1  1/1/2019  20  10     5
2  2/1/2019  25  20    10
3  3/1/2019  30  15    10

master = df2.merge(new_df1, on='Date', suffixes=("","_Price"))
##print(master[['Date','Type','Ac','Ac_Price','Fan','Fan_Price','Chair','Chair_Price']])

       Date       Type  Ac Ac_Price  Fan Fan_Price  Chair Chair_Price
0  1/1/2019    AC, FAN   6       20    5        10      0           5
1  2/1/2019         Ac   4       25    0        20      0          10
2  3/1/2019  Chair,Fan   0       30    4        15      8          10
```

Comment: i am getting error in this line-master = PlanEffData.merge(new_Data, on='Date', suffixes=("","_Price"))--- # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce- @iamklaus

Comment: okay try the updates...df1 is df with type and dates as header...also if the error persist then you may have to convert the type of Date column to string using strftime...

Comment: Hi @iamklaus, could you pls help how to apply strftime in the current code.